# Cerrar conexión de java con firebase

Tags: java, firebase

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio en java, el cual debe recoger los datos que yo ingrese y registrarlos en firebase.

Al abrir la ventana de registros por primera vez si me permite registrar datos las veces que yo quiera, el problema viene cuando yo cierro y la vuelvo a abrir y ya no me permite hacer el registro.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already 
exists!
at com.google.firebase.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:180)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:160)
at firebase.Admin_Firebase.initFirebase(Admin_Firebase.java:125)
at firebase.Admin_Firebase.registrar(Admin_Firebase.java:171)
at 
firebase.VentAvisosMeca.BPUblicarActionPerformed(VentAvisosMeca.java:2058)
at firebase.VentAvisosMeca.access$300(VentAvisosMeca.java:13)
at firebase.VentAvisosMeca$4.actionPerformed(VentAvisosMeca.java:307)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)


at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege( 
ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

[image: Este es el bloque al que me dirige el error, más específicamente en la linea FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions)]

Me imagino que debo cerrar la conexión y volver a crearla, pero no sé como cerrarla, o quizás sea otra cosa

Comment: Hola, buen día. Es preferible que coloques el código y no solo una imagen. Además de la salida completa del Stack para entender mejor el problema. Por lo que puedo entender, el problema está en la configuración de la aplicación. Un nombre duplicado que provoca que trate de iniciar dos veces la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

No colocas mucho sobre la configuración de tu aplicación. Lo que entiendo es que llamas más de una vez la conexión.

Podrías hacer algo como esto cuando ya no la uses:

```
firebaseDataBase.delete();
```